# Determine $ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d}{dx} (\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}) $

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to determine this limit $$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d}{dx} (\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}) $$ but I can't find a way to solve it. At first I tried to put the limit inside the derivative: $$ \frac{d}{dx}(\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}) = 0 $$ which was wrong. Then I tried to solve $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{x}{1+x}-\ln(1+x)}{x^2}$$ but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Hint : Make asymptotic development of $\ln(1+x)= .. + .. +o(x^4)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's a $\dfrac{0}{0}$ form, you can use De l'Hôpital rule, hence you take the separate derivatives of numerator and denominator, and you get:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{-\frac{x}{(x+1)^2}}{2x} = \lim_{x\to 0} -\dfrac{1}{2(1+x)^2} = -\dfrac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_0\frac{\frac{x}{x+1}-\ln(1+x)}{x^2}=$$

$$\lim_0\frac{x-(1+x)\ln(1+x)}{x^2(1+x)}=$$

$$\lim_0\frac{x-(1+x)\ln(1+x)}{x^2}$$

but

$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}(1+\epsilon(x))$$

and
$$(1+x)\ln(1+x)=$$
$$x-\frac{x^2}{2}+x^2(1+\epsilon(x))$$

thus
$$L=\lim_0\frac{-\frac{x^2}{2}+x^2\epsilon(x)}{x^2}=-\frac 12$$

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use L'hopital or series expansion, then I suggest the following :

Notice that : $$ \frac{\frac{x}{1+x}-\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{x^{2}}=\frac{1}{1+x}\left(\frac{x-\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{x^{2}}-\frac{\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{x}\right) $$

You may recognize the well-known limit $ \lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{x-\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{x^{2}}} $, that, we'll be proving, equals $ \frac{1}{2} $ :

Let $ x\in\left(-1,1\right)\setminus\left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace $, note that : $$ \frac{x-\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{x^{2}}=\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{1-y}{\left(1+xy\right)^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}y}=\frac{1}{2}-x\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{y\left(2+xy\right)}{\left(1+xy\right)^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}y} $$

Since : \begin{aligned} \left|x\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{y\left(2+xy\right)}{\left(1+xy\right)^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}y}\right|&\leq\left|x\right|\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{y\left(2+\left|x\right|y\right)}{\left(1-\left|x\right|y\right)^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}y}\\ &\leq\frac{\left|x\right|\left(2+\left|x\right|\right)}{2\left(1-\left|x\right|\right)^{2}}\underset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}0 \end{aligned}

Then : $$ \lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{x-\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{x^{2}}}=\frac{1}{2} $$

Thus : \begin{aligned}\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x\mapsto\frac{\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{x}\right)\left(x\right)}&=\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{1}{1+x}\left(\frac{x-\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{x^{2}}-\frac{\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{x}\right)}\\ &=1\times\left(\frac{1}{2}-1\right)\\&=-\frac{1}{2}\end{aligned}

$\underline{\textrm{Note :}} $ You may have noticed that I prefer to use the notation $ \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x\right) =f'\left(x\right) $, rather than $ \frac{\mathrm{d}f\left(x\right)}{\mathrm{d}x}=\left(f\left(x\right)\right)' $, which in my mind, doesn't stand for the derivative of $ f $ at $ x $, but stands for the derivative of the image of $ x $ by $ f $, which sould be $ 0 $.